# Git: suggestion for applying patches when the source is known to have changed substantially

Tags: git, patch

About five months ago now, we started on a project to overhaul and upgrade a legacy PHP-4/5 application, moving it to PHP-7 (and many other things).  This application consists of more than 2,700 files, and extensive changes have been made to almost all of them.

Meanwhile, the legacy application continues to support the customer, and so-far about 250 changes have been made.  I have (and can make ...) `git` patches to represent those changes.  My immediate problem is that most of them do not `git apply`.

It is, of course, easy to see why:  "line numbers," as expressed in the patch, are pretty-much useless.  Although in most cases the source-code being looked-for *is* there, it might have been moved some distance.

My present thinking *(based on the examination of about 30 of the patch files)* is that in usefully-many cases the literal source-code that is to be patched *is* still present, verbatim, in the source file, just not at the expected place.

Although I am realist enough to know that many of these patches will have to be analyzed and made by hand, I would like to minimize this, both for the sake of time and for accuracy.  I would like for the folks who will be doing this ... including me(!) ... to be able to leverage automated tools as much as possible, knowing that they will then have to check their work per-patch.  I have no illusions that I'm likely to be able to do all these files at once, automagically, *"Shazam.*"

Therefore, who out there has dealt with a similar situation?  What do you suggest that I do?  One suggestion has been to use the `patch` command, with a `fuzz` option, that, it is cautioned, may work *or* may cause an incorrect patch to be applied.

(We plan to do one patch at a time in any case: *"patch, `git commit`, rinse and repeat."*  So that we can `git diff` to check each change for sanity.)

"War stories" requested.  Thanks.

Comment: Great question; based on your other question I was really interested in the bigger context.  I really hope that you create a blog post or something when you're done, it would be really fascinating.

Answer (score 5):

`git apply` provides several options that can be used to apply patches heuristically or semi-manually, most of which are described on the  [`git-apply(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) manual page:

- [`-C`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#Documentation/git-apply.txt--Cltngt) can reduce the number of context lines that have to match in the hunk for patching to succeed.

  > `-C<n>`
  >
  > Ensure at least `<n>` lines of surrounding context match before and after each change. When fewer lines of surrounding context exist they all must match. By default no context is ever ignored.
- [`--recount`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#Documentation/git-apply.txt---recount) will ignore line numbers.

  > `--recount`
  >
  > Do not trust the line counts in the hunk headers, but infer them by inspecting the patch (e.g. after editing the patch without adjusting the hunk headers appropriately).
- [`--reject`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#Documentation/git-apply.txt---reject) will leave hunks that fail to apply in `.rej` files, like `patch` does. You can then inspect those files and apply the changes manually.

  > `--reject`
  >
  > For atomicity, `git apply` by default fails the whole patch and does not touch the working tree when some of the hunks do not apply. This option makes it apply the parts of the patch that are applicable, and leave the rejected hunks in corresponding *.rej files.
- [`--3way`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#Documentation/git-apply.txt--3) will attempt a three-way merge, assuming the patches were generated by git in the first place.

  > `-3`
  >
  > `--3way`
  >
  > When the patch does not apply cleanly, fall back on 3-way merge if the patch records the identity of blobs it is supposed to apply to, and we have those blobs available locally, possibly leaving the conflict markers in the files in the working tree for the user to resolve. This option implies the `--index` option, and is incompatible with the `--reject` and the `--cached` options.

Personally, I have used `git apply -C1 --recount` with some success to convert quilt patches into git commits.

Alternatively, you may simply use the `patch` utility to apply the patch, without using the `git apply` command at all. By default `patch` will apply hunks fuzzily and leave hunks that entirely fail to apply in `.rej` files; if the `--merge` option is given, failing hunks will generate conflict markers instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar experiences. Our team is working on Google's Android Codebases of different chipsets and different versions. The so-called common issuses or features are ported or reused from one codebase to another.

If it's from Android M to Android M, it's easier. But we have issues from Android L to Android M or to Android N. Some of the patches, often hundreds, can hardly be applied directly. And the git patches are ++-- diff, which are not clear or straightforward enough and are driving us mad when we have to apply them by hand.

The codebase is composed of over 400 git repos. So we make a list of commits sorted by date for each repo. And we make a before-after patch for each commit. A before-after patch is a side by side patch. The left are the files before the change, and the right are the files after the change. The patch folder structure is like `<commit>/before`, `<commit>/after`. So we can easily use a tool like 'Beyond Compare' to see the changes in a more friendly way.

We have a script to make the before-after patch. It's basically like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 

#takes one parameter, the commit
commit=$1

#copy the modified files after the change
git checkout -f $commit
git log -1 $commit --name-only --pretty=%h | tail -n +3 | while read line
do
mkdir -p ~/backup/$commit/after/$(dirname $line)
cp -v $line ~/backup/$commit/after/$line
done

#copy the same files before the change
git checkout -f $commit^
git log -1 $commit --name-only --pretty=%h | tail -n +3 | while read line
do
mkdir -p ~/backup/$commit/before/$(dirname $line)
cp -v $line ~/backup/$commit/before/$line
done
```

Both the diff patches and the before-after patches and lists are then delivered to the team members. If a git diff patch cannot be applied automatically, we just follow the before-after patch to apply it by hand. Though the workload is tough, it's to be finished.

Comment: Interesting.  Now, are those "before-after patches" *entire files?*  By "++/--" are you referring to the ordinary differential patches that `git` normally produces, or are you doing anything special to make them?

Comment: *Four Hundred* `git` repos?  Gee, suddenly I don't feel quite so bad.  **;-)**

Comment: @MikeRobinson yes, they are files with full contents. Since the new git supports `git worktree`, it could be another possible option. But I have not learned about it yet.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Google has invented a tool called "Repo" to manage the four hundred repos. It's capable of managing multiple repos. So it's actually not a big deal :)

Comment: @MikeRobinson By "++/--" I am referring to patches generated by `git format-patch`.

Comment: Thought so ...  The patches I've generated so far *(I've got the whole repo ...)* are that way, too.  Not sure yet  if I can experiment with any other patch-making options to any good effect . . .

Comment: @MikeRobinson By `git worktree` I mean it could be an alternative of the before-after patch since it can checkout different revisions into different work trees.

Comment: I'll have to look into it, but without too much hope in my case.  In my situation, I think that I"m going to need to look for `diff` options that basically *ignore* line-numbers. In most cases that I've examined so far, the source-regions that have been modified *do exist* somewhere in the "new" code, but not "close to" the original line-numbers.  Still, thanks for the heads-up.  I'll put that new fee-chur on my watch list.